# C++: struct accessing instance of itself

Tags: c++, vector, struct, initialization

I have come across a rather unusual issue in my code. A `struct` needs to be able to access instances of itself.

Relavent portion of code:

```
struct crtr {
  char f;
  void foo() {
    for(int i=0; i<creatures[f].size(); i++) {/*code that accesses creatures[f][i]*/}
  }
};

vector<crtr> creatures[10];
```

Of course, this is nowhere close to working - `crtr.foo()` requires `creatures`, while `creatures` requires `crtr`. Is there some way to initialize `creatures` before `crtr`, perhaps changing the `vector`s' data type? (preferably with minimal pointers, if possible)

Comment: You can pass that array of vectors as a parameter to `foo()`: `void foo(vector<crtr> creatures[10])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must be missing something, what's wrong with this?

```
struct crtr {
  char f;
  void foo();
};

vector<crtr> creatures[10];

void crtr::foo() {
    for(int i=0; i<creatures[f].size(); i++) {/*code that accesses creatures[f][i]*/}
}
```

Also `crtr::foo` can be inline if that's required.

Answer (score 1):

Use forward declaration of the struct:

```
struct crtr;

vector<crtr> creatures[10];

struct crtr {
    char f;
    void foo() {
        for(int i=0; i<creatures[f].size(); i++) {/*code that accesses creatures[f][i]*/}
    }
};
```